# iOS returns wrong language setting

Tags: ios, localization

I have a localized app, but most time **it uses the base localization (en) when it is set to another language**. This happens on the devices and the simulator.
To check what it wrong, I inserted

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

in `viewDidLoad` of the 1st screen, and it returns *en* as the language, even when the settings have another language as the 1st language, and it is selected. Moreover, the device as well as the simulator are really set to this other  (mlanguage, since everything else is displayed in the selected language, only my app is in English (most of the time, sometimes it uses the correct language).
This looks like a bug in iOS, and I have no idea what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: You've spotted that iOS allows language and region format to be set separately?

Comment: Yes, I know. But this is not a question of the region format. When I set the 1st preferred language, say to German, and the simulator and device language IS German, every app should use the German localization.